# The project target is not set. Right click project, choose Properties | Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am importing an `Android` application in `Eclipse` as a `Gradle` build. The application is build and runs fine. When I try to see the layouts defined in XML I can, but when I switch over to the `Graphical Layout` I get

`The project target is not set. Right click project, choose Properties | Android.`

What I did:

Right click `Project->Properties` to find the Android tab but is not there.(*see picture 3)[image: Picture 3]
On the Graphical Layout there is a switch that is supposed to be pointing to the latest API available. Instead it says: Null(*see first picture)[image: First Picture]
When I try to change it I get `Resource ...... does not exist` prompts (*see second picture).[image: Second Picture]

How can I open the `XML` layouts in the `Graphical Layout`?

Comment: why don't you switch to Android Studio ?

Answer (score 0):

please check whether set SDK location.as follows:
Eclipse -> Preferences -> Android

Comment: That is not a solution to my problem. The SDK location has already been set.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT click (not Right) and select Android worked for me.